# Netlogo model result conveying method

Tags: statistics, simulation, netlogo

I have designed a netlogo model which outputs number of turtles in each run. Number of turtles increases with ticks and becomes constant to a value N. I run the model 50 times and I have the data with 50 different N values varying from 9 to 12. I have to report the result with a graph showing number of turtles increasing with the ticks. For one simulation it will become constant at 9 (N = 9) and for some other it will become constant at 10 (N = 10).

For which simulation out of the 50, should I draw the graph for?
or
Should I take the average of 50 values for each tick, and draw a graph for that?

What is the right approach to convey that in my result, confirmed by 50 simulations, the number of turtles increases with ticks and becomes constant (which varies in the range of (9 - 12) for different simulations) ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question may be too vague. You'll have to describe your purpose of the experiments and a little background knowledge--depending on what you're doing, you'll need different statistical analysis.

Comment: The purpose of the experiment: To show that no. of turtles increase with time and become constant because of a decision rule. The  decision rule comes from a natural phenomenon and the turtles reproduce according to the rule.
The result has to be reported in a scientific report so statistical analysis which conveys the observed behaver is needed.
Please let me know if you need any other description, thank you.

Comment: So to be clear, your model has four possible outcomes (9, 10, 11, 12) and those outcomes are predetermined by the type of behavioral rule being used?

I'm not sure you should be comparing the runs at all with stats since the results are always consistent because it worked like you programmed it to, not that it worked because of any sort of stochasticity.

Comment: It is working because of stochastic behavior. Initially on setup, random attributes are assigned to patches. The decision rule uses these attributes to decide number of turtles. 
In each run initial random values change which leads to change in outcomes. The outcome is any floating point value in [9-12] but for physical number of turtles it is rounded-off to nearest integer.
I have to report the floating point value too.

Answer (score 0):

The point of doing multiple simulations is to average out the stochastic effects. Without seeing your data, the most appropriate graph is probably one that averages your variable of interest (eg final turtle count, or turtle count at each tick). That average should be taken across the simulations that are running the same scenario (that is, have the same starting parameters) if you want to compare scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! So the average comes around to be 10.9

So along with the graph of average turtle count at each tick, if I report the maximum (12) and minimum (9), is that sufficient to describe the result?

Could there be any other method than averaging just to be thorough

Comment: You need to think about why you have done the simulations in the first place. What question are you trying to answer? For example, if you think that the number of starting turtles changes the ticks until the system stabilises, then you would have (say) 50 simulations for 1 starting turtle, another 50 for 2 starting turtles etc. For each simulation you would report the tick at which the simulation stabilises. Then you would take the average of those times for the 50 simulations with 1 starting turtle, and the average over 50 simulations for 2 starting turtles etc. ...

Comment: Using those averages would give you a plot with y axis of 'average stabilisation ticks over 50 simultions' and x axis of 'number of starting turtles'. You would look at that plot to see if there was any relationship, answering your initial question.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that I am always starting with 0 turtles for all the 50 simulations. I have defined an attribute for the patches which can take value within a range [ 0 - 1] randomly using "random" keyword.
So when one simulation runs, a random value is assigned to each patch. Then there is a rule which evaluates  these attributes and returns number of turtles. With time these attributes of patches change and in turn change the number of turtles till the system stabilizes. 
I have done multiple simulations because in each simulation a new value is assigned to the attribute of patches.

Comment: so what is your research question? from your comments above it is something about different decision rules. presumably you have sets of simulations for each decision rule option?

Comment: Lets say in sim1 patchxy has a value 0.8 and it results in stabalization at 10 turtles.
In sim2 patchxy has a value 0.4 and it results in stabalization at 9.5 turtles.
So for 50 simulations due to randomness of the attribute of patches different stabilization points occur. Although the stabalization is different as it should be, it always lies in the range( 9 -12)

Comment: The research question is that if patches have an attribute with different random values in the range [0-1]  then how do turtles populate from 0 to a final number. and what is the final number. My simulation shows they increase with time and the final number can vary in the range 9-12 depending the random values of the attribute of all the patches we started with. 
The decision rule is the same, attribute of patches is changing randomly in each simulation.
I think your statement "The point of doing multiple simulations is to average out the stochastic effects." makes sense here...